# How does this makefile make objectfiles?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I hava a just simple question. I made a just simple Makefile like this

```
OBJ = main.o Str.o Out.o
CC = g++
TAR = main

$(TAR):$(OBJ) Header.h
    $(CC) -o $(TAR) $(OBJ)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TAR)
```

I have just `Str.cpp`, `Out.cpp`, `main.cpp` in my current directory. 
Even if I miss the process which converts source file into objectfile
(like g++ -c Str.cpp), it works well.

I'm curious why this Makefile works. Does it make objectfiles automatically??

Comment: The `make` program has *implicit rules* so that it knows how to create an object file from a source file. If you're on Linux you most likely have GNU Make, please [read its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for more information.

Comment: `make` actually has a lot of implicit rules, like, in your example, `$(CC)` is implicitly set to `cc` of your environment.

Comment: Instead of changing the `CC` variable to `g++` you should simply use `$(CXX)` in the link line.

Answer (score 3):

## [10.2 Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)

> Compiling C++ programs
>
> **n.o** is made automatically from n.cc, **n.cpp**, or n.C with a recipe of the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’. We encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of ‘.C’.

The answer is yes, it creates object files in the same directory for each source file (and then links them all with your rule to final executable).